# Prevent a method to be called before recursion is finished

Tags: java, recursion

I have a method that we can call recMethod. It looks like this:

```
 public void recMethod(String path) {
 Arrays here: fileName, filePath.
 for (File file : listOfFiles)
        {
            if(file.isDir()) {
                Some stuff here
                Add to the array filePath
                //The recursive call
                recMethod(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            else if (file.isFile()){
                Add to the array fileName
            }
        }
        toDatabase(fileName, filePath);
    }
```

So now the thing: As you can see there is a call on the method `toDatabase` in the end of my code. It get's called everytime there is a recursive call in the for loop. This is not what I want and my problem that I want help with. I only want the method `toDatabase` to be called once the recursion is finished. The current solution is working fine but the problem is that the method gets called unnecessary many times.

Is there a way to first let the recursion finish and then do the rest outside of it? Like calling on the `toDatabase`?

Comment: Why not just have a top-level method that calls `recMethod` and *then* `toDatabase`, and remove the `toDatabase` call from `recMethod`?

Comment: Absolutely, your `recMethod` returns void. so basically there is no need to call `toDatabase` inside it.

Comment: I just updated the code, I forgot to mention that fileName, filePath are arrays that are sent to toDatabase. These arrays are filled trough the recursion.

Comment: Another way to do this would be to add a boolean parameter to the method which is `true` when called from the outside but always false when called while performing the recursion.

Comment: @Leon Oh yeah, this sounds interesting. Could you please give an example?